# How to factorize selected columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to implement a function that automatically assigns a numeric value to an object.
Here is my code:

```
column_list = ['datum', 'parameter_name', 'sample_duration', 'pollutant_standard', 'units_of_measure']
def gnumeric_func(data, columns):
    data[columns] = pd.factorize(data.columns)[0]

data = pd.DataFrame(data, column_list)
gnumeric_func(data, column_list)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is it doing wrong? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
def gnumeric_func (data, columns):
  data[columns] = data[columns].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
  return data
```

For all columns:

```
def gnumeric_func (data):
  data = data.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
  return data
```

Comment: Is it good practice to mutate the input `data` and return it?

Comment: @JoeCondron - I think in python it is common, but if it is good practice it is hard question for me. I really have no idea.